# Ambient light sensor support

Tags: kernel, hardware, brightness, vaio

I have a 2010 Sony Vaio laptop running Ubuntu 12.10, with an ambient light sensor installed to adjust screen brightness automatically. However, last time I checked, this was not supported by default in the Linux kernel, and apparently I had to [patch the kernel](https://code.google.com/p/vaio-f11-linux/wiki/KernelSupport) to get it to work. My question is, were those patches already included in the latest Linux kernel?